# Is there a collection more suitable for this scenario than an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a method that will need to return a set of data, and the current plan is to use an ArrayList of ArrayList, however I am unsure if there is a collection that is more suitable.

- The collection has a fixed number of rows. It has n groups per collection, which will remain constant.
- The collection has a fixed number of data entries. They are simply distributed across the rows of the collection in an unknown distribution.
- We do not know the length of each row before the input data has finished processing.

This abstract nature lead me to believe that each row would be best represented by an ArrayList, as this could has entries added to it before finally adding that ArrayList to the main ArrayList.

Is there a better way to do this, particularly with regards to performance?

Comment: If you know the size of the data ahead of time, you could put it in a 2d array.   However, I wouldn't worry too much about the nested list structure until the data gets unweildy.  I've struggled in Java with similar structures, due to a lack of nd-array like `numpy` in python

Comment: Which operations does your datastructure need to supply and are there any time or storage constraints? Is there a maximum length for all rows or are they possibly infinite?

Comment: If you know the exact number of rows and columns you can use a two dimensional array. This uses less memory and will be faster too.

Comment: Since the rows are fixed, but the columns aren't; you can use a combination of both `arrays` and `ArrayLists`.

Comment: Datastructure just needs to hold strings which are used elsewhere as references, nothing too complex in terms of operations. There is a hard limit on the maximum length of an array since all the data could just end up in one group, so a 2D array could be possible if I declared the array with the number of rows and the maximum length, but is that optimal?

Comment: Are all rows the same length, including the last row?

Comment: Also, is every string unique within the whole data set? If not, what percentage are unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the number of rows is fixed (let us say 10) and the number off columns not, then you can use an array of lists like e.g:

```
// Use whatever type you need instead of Integer.
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Integer>[] arrayOfLists = new ArrayList[10];
```

This code issues a warning "generic array creation". For this reason I have added `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Answer (score 1):

There is little complicated way (But performance is good because of direct access to data) how the have the collection which has the row represented by groupKey (rowKey) and colums represented by comlunKey. Here you can add optional object.
In simple way it is map of maps.

```
/**
 * representation of bi dimensional array with dynamical size
 *
 * @param <K> - type of row key
 * @param <L> - type of columne key
 * @param <V> - type of value
 */
public class CustomCollection<K, L, V> extends HashMap<K, Map<L, V>> {

public CustomCollection() {

}

/**
 * add new entry on particular row and column
 *
 * @param rowKey    - key of row
 * @param columnKey - key of column
 * @param value     - value to add
 */
public void addNewEntry(K rowKey, L columnKey, V value) {
    Map<L, V> columns = get(rowKey);
    if (columns == null) {
        columns = new HashMap<>();
        put(rowKey, columns);
    }
    columns.put(columnKey, value);
}

/**
 * get exact value on current row represented by {@code rowKey} and column represented by {@code columnKey}
 *
 * @param rowKey    - key of row
 * @param columnKey - key of column
 * @return
 */
public V getExactValue(K rowKey, V columnKey) {
    Map<L, V> columns = get(rowKey);
    if (columns == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return columns.get(columnKey);
}

/**
 * get colums values as map
 *
 * @param rowKey - key of row
 * @return
 */
public Map<L, V> getColumsAsMap(K rowKey) {
    return get(rowKey);
}

/**
 * get colums values as map
 *
 * @param rowKey - key of row
 * @return
 */
public Collection<V> getColumsAsCollection(K rowKey) {
    Map<L, V> columns = get(rowKey);
    if (columns == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return columns.values();
}

/**
 * remove value on particular index
 *
 * @param rowKey
 * @param columnKey
 *
 * @return - removed item
 */
public V removeExactValue(K rowKey, L columnKey){
    Map<L, V> columns = get(rowKey);
    if (columns == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return columns.remove(columnKey);
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    final StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    keySet().forEach(rowKey -> {
        stringBuffer.append(rowKey + " = {");
        Map<L, V> columns = get(rowKey);
        if (columns != null) {
            columns.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
                stringBuffer.append("["+entry.getKey()+"="+entry.getValue()+"]");
            });
        }
        stringBuffer.append("}\n");
    });
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
}

// Sample how to use it

public static void main(String [] args){
    CustomCollection<Integer,Integer,String> customCollection = new CustomCollection<>();
    customCollection.addNewEntry(1,1, "v_1_1");
    customCollection.addNewEntry(1,2,"v_1_2");
    customCollection.addNewEntry(2,1,"v_2_1");
    customCollection.addNewEntry(2,2,"v_2_2");
    customCollection.addNewEntry(2,3,"v_2_3");
    System.out.println(customCollection.toString());
    System.out.println("After remove:");
    customCollection.removeExactValue(2,2);
    customCollection.removeExactValue(2,3);
    System.out.println(customCollection.toString());
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder?

Comment: Possibly due to thread safety, that tends to be why I've seen it used whenever I see it over StringBuilder.

Comment: StringBuilder can be used as well.There is not need to use thread safe toString implementation for this example. Each call create new builder therefore it is true that the StringBuilder is better fit

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there is the concept of **Jagged Arrays**. It's essentially that same as you describe. You can either implement it in one of two ways.

1. A 2-D Array where you initialize the rows when you declare the variable, and declare each column when you need to use it.
2. An array of Lists, where you declare the rows when you initialize it, and just add items (columns) to each index in the rows when needed.

**2-D Array Approach**

```
// Initialize the rows only for now
String[][] arr = new String[3][];

// Process some data to know the column sizes of each
// ...
arr[0] = new String[] {"Foo", "Bar", "FooBar"};
arr[1] = new String[] {"Jane", "Doe"};
arr[2] = new String[] {"Peter", "Parker", "Tony", "Stark"};
// ...
// Printing 
for(String[] row : arr) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.ToString(row));
}
```

**Array of Lists Approach**

```
// Initialize the rows only for now
List<String> [] arr = new List[3];

// Process some data
// ...
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("Foo");
list1.add("Bar");
list1.add("FooBar");
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add("Jane");
list2.add("Doe");
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
list3.add("Peter");
list3.add("Parker");
list3.add("Tony");
list3.add("Stark");
// ...
// Printing
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
    List<String> temp = arr[i];
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Based on your needs, since you know that your data set will **always** remain fixed. You just don't know the length of each row in the Jagged Array. Based on this, Go with the plain 2-D approach.

Now, If you think the requirements are going to change later down the road, or you like the useful methods that `ArrayLists` have (`contains` etc.) then I would go with an `Array` of `ArrayLists`.

You will not notice a significant performance difference between the two implementations unless the data set is huge. If you are experiencing performance issues then go with the 2-D array approach.

If it was up to me, I would go with the `Array` of `ArrayLists` approach. I would go with this because:

1. `ArrayLists` can be expanded easily if your data set would ever happen to change.
2. `ArrayLists` also offer plenty useful methods that are easier to just call then have to implement yourself.
3. `ArrayLists` also they implement `Iterable`, `Collection`, and `List`, and can therefore be used in a lot of API calls that are interface-based.

Some methods that `ArrayLists` can do are [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-arraylist).

More about Jagged arrays can be found [here](http://www.techiedelight.com/jagged-array-ragged-array-java/).

Comment: The "useful methods that ArrayLists have (contains etc)" are also available for plain arrays through the `Arrays` utility class. And if you really want a List, you can always get a `List` view of your array through `Arrays.asList`. But I think the main obstacle with using plain arrays is that you don't know how many elements each row has until after you've read all elements.